# Split list of lists in unique combinations without overlapping elements

Tags: python, list, math

I have a list of lists similar to this one:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [3, 5, 6]]
```

I would like to split it in a way that shows all combinations where every list do not have elements of the other lists:

```
[
  [[1, 2, 3], [4], [5, 6]],
  [[1, 2], [4], [3, 5, 6]],
  [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]],
  [[1], [2, 3, 4], [5, 6]],
  [[1], [2, 4], [3, 5, 6]]
]
```

Can you point me to the most pythonic way of doing so?

Thanks!

Comment: You seem to exclude things like `[[1], [3], [5]]` where not all elements appear in some list.  Is this required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a canonical `powerset` [recipe](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes)

I use a modified version here that does not allow the empty subset.

Then we combine all subsets and filter for those with no duplicates.  If you want to require that all elements that appear in one the original lists are used somewhere, then the function `no_duplicates` could be edited to check that too.

```
from itertools import chain, combinations, product
from pprint import pprint

flatten = lambda l: [item for sublist in l for item in sublist]

def powerset(iterable):
    "powerset([1,2,3]) --> () (1,) (2,) (3,) (1,2) (1,3) (2,3) (1,2,3)"
    s = list(iterable)
    return list(chain.from_iterable(combinations(s, r) for r in range(1, len(s)+1)))

def no_duplicates(l):
    f = flatten(l)
    return len(set(f)) == len(f)

a = [[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [3, 5, 6]]

pprint(list(filter(no_duplicates, product(*list(powerset(x) for x in a)))))
```

Comment: Thanks! I needed that all elements of the original list appear in the other lists, so I used ```list_len = len(set(flatten(a)))``` and changed the return of no_duplicates to ```return (len(set(f)) == len(f)) and (len(set(f)) == list_len)```.